# NodeJS Server Response of Different Content-Types

Tags: node.js

I have a question regarding pure NodeJS as I am starting to learn the basic concepts.

My question is as following:

I have a simple WebPage

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>HomePage</title>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./tailwind.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div
            class="
                h-screen
                w-screen
                bg-gradient-to-r
                from-yellow-400
                via-red-500
                to-pink-500
                flex flex-col
                items-center
            "
        >
            <h1
                class="
                    flex
                    justify-center
                    items-center
                    m-10
                    bg-white bg-opacity-50
                    rounded
                    p-2
                    h-20
                    w-auto
                    text-white text-2xl
                "
            >
                Welcome to my HomePage
            </h1>
            <p class="m-2">
                This is my first Node JS Project. A simple Server-Side Webpage
            </p>
            <div
                class="
                    flex
                    justify-center
                    items-center
                    m-1
                    p-2
                    bg-white bg-opacity-50
                    rounded
                    h-auto
                    w-auto
                    text-white text-2xl
                "
            >
                <button
                    class="
                        flex
                        justify-center
                        items-center
                        m-1
                        p-2
                        bg-white bg-opacity-50
                        rounded
                        h-10
                        w-48
                        text-white text-lg
                    "
                    onclick="localhost:8080/about"
                >
                    About
                </button>
                <button
                    class="
                        flex
                        justify-center
                        items-center
                        m-1
                        p-2
                        bg-white bg-opacity-50
                        rounded
                        h-10
                        w-48
                        text-white text-lg
                    "
                    onclick="localhost:8080/contact"
                >
                    Contact Me
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a tailwind.css file in the same directory. When I make a request to my NodeJS, I do get both index.html as well as tailwind.css.

My problem: Even though tailwind.css is delivered, I do not have the styling applied.

There are two versions of my NodeJS code. One that does work and another that doesn't.

Maybe you can explain to me why.

Correct code:

```
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

http
    .createServer(function (req, res) {
        let filePath = path.join(
            __dirname,
            '../public',
            req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url
        );
        let extname = path.extname(filePath);
        let contentType = 'text/html';

        switch (extname) {
            case '.js':
                contentType = 'text/javascript';
                break;
            case '.css':
                contentType = 'text/css';
                break;
            case '.json':
                contentType = 'application/json';
                break;
            case '.png':
                contentType = 'image/png';
                break;
            case '.jpg':
                contentType = 'image/jpg';
                break;
        }

         fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content)=> {
            if (err) throw err

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType})
            res.write(content)
            res.end()
         })
        
    })
    .listen(8080);
```

wrong code:

````
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

http
    .createServer(function (req, res) {
        let filePath = path.join(
            __dirname,
            '../public',
            req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url
        );
        let extname = path.extname(filePath);
        let contentType = 'text/html';

        

         fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content)=> {
            if (err) throw err

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType})
            res.write(content)
            res.end()
         })
        
    })
    .listen(8080);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your `link` for styleshits are wrong, you are using relative paths that are looking for the file on the file system, what you should do instead is using an absolute path to your server.

```
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/tailwind.css" />
```

Comment: The difference between my two code snippets is a switch statement which evaluates the Content-Type of a file. I assume in the fist code snippet, the server searches for a tailwind.css.html file because content-type is set to html.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the path package to define the path to your static assets but you're referencing them the wrong way

`<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./tailwind.css" />`

(This is js syntax you are writing inside html which is even wrong, you can use '..' to go to a previous directory but '.' doesn't work to reference the current directory inside html, only in js files)

It should be

`<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tailwind.css" />`

(since it is in the same directory, path takes care of the rest)

Comment: This is not correct. The problem lies in the switch statement. It i necessary to function. I assume this is because tailwind.css is linked but you also have to specify the Content-Type of each data.